# How to Shade in Only Part of Overlapping Parabolas

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

[image]

I want to shade in the parabola facing up but only the area where the two aren't intersecting which is the area (0,-2) to (0,2).

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                samples=1000,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
            xmin=-4.5,xmax=4.5,
                ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,
            grid=both,
                grid style={line width=.01pt, draw=black!25},
            major grid style={line width=.1pt},
                axis lines=middle,
            x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north, below=-5mm},
            minor x tick num=3,
            minor y tick num=3,
            ticklabel style={font=\small},
            enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
                ]
            \addplot[smooth,domain = -6:6,name path = A]{x^2-2};
            \addplot[smooth,domain = -6:6,name path = B]{2-x^2};
            \addplot[draw=none,name path = C]{6};
            \addplot[gray,opacity=0.2] fill between[of=A and C,soft clip={domain=-10:10}];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is code I have so far.

Comment: it would be helpful to share your code

Comment: Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For shading only overlapped part of parabolas you can use options `split` and `every even segment/.style={...}`:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}       % it load tikz too
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}   % it is very recommended to be added
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                backgrounds,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                % snakes is part of decorations.pathmorphing 
                }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    x label style={anchor=north east},
    xmin=-4.5,  xmax=4.5,   xlabel=$x$,
    ymin=-4.5,  ymax=4.5,   ylabel=$y$,
    grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt},
    major grid style={line width=.1pt, black!75},
    minor x tick num=3,
    minor y tick num=3,
    ticklabel style={font=\small},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    domain = -6:6, samples=101,
    every axis plot post/.append style={thick}
        ]
    \addplot[name path = A]{x^2-2};
    \addplot[name path = B]{2-x^2};
    \addplot[gray,opacity=0.2] 
        fill between[of=A and B, split,
                     every even segment/.style={fill=none}];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can notice, in the above MWE the following changes have been made compared to yours:

- removed is loading of the `tikz` package since it is loaded by `pgfplots`
- added is `\pgfplotsset`
- obsolete `snake` library is replaced by `decorations.pathmorphing`
- changed is `x label style`
- changed is `grid style` (that minor grid is better visible)
- changed is `major grid style` (that it is better visible)
- functions cures are thicker
- removes is not used `\addplot

Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like that:
I am not very familiar with pgf plots. I only found that you wanted to draw the area between plot A and C. By changing C with B it draws the area between function A and B. then you just have to adjust `soft clip={domain=< >}`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                samples=1000,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
            xmin=-4.5,xmax=4.5,
                ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,
            grid=both,
                grid style={line width=.01pt, draw=black!25},
            major grid style={line width=.1pt},
                axis lines=middle,
            x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north, below=-5mm},
            minor x tick num=3,
            minor y tick num=3,
            ticklabel style={font=\small},
            enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
                ]
            \addplot[smooth,domain = -6:6,name path = A]{x^2-2};
            \addplot[smooth,domain = -6:6,name path = B]{2-x^2};
            \addplot[draw=none,name path = C]{6};
            \addplot[gray,opacity=0.2] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-1.5:1.5}];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]